# Is there a way of having Amazon automatically buy an item when it hits a certain price?

Tags: amazon

I've got a few things in my Amazon wishlist that I'd like, but are too expensive right now. The prices tend to fluctuate, and I'd like to buy it once it's below a certain price. Can this be done?

Comment: That looks exactly what I'm looking for - you should make that an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sign up at http://camelcamelcamel.com to get email alerts when prices drop at Amazon.

Answer (score 3):

Now you could do this with https://waatcher.com. You just search for the item you want to buy, set a target price and Waatcher will buy it for you when the price drops below your set price.

Waatcher also have a dashboard where you can track all the products that you are buying with a price change feed. There is a price history report, deal estimate and product review videos.

Comment: FYI. From https://waatcher.com/ "Waatcher is inoperable and will be shut down soon. "

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done.

First, you need to create a way to check the product's price. You could use Amazon's Product Advertising API, or another method (e.g. web scraping with PhantomJS). If this is all you need, you could use prebuilt tools like [camelcamelcamel](http://camelcamelcamel.com) or thetracktor.com.

Next, you need a way to complete the purchase. The [Zinc API](http://zinc.io) will allow you to place an order to Amazon on your account using a couple of API calls. Your script could make these calls when the price drops below your threshold to complete the purchase.

Comment: You can call the the [Zinc API](https://zinc.io/docs) from either your java android app or the backend for your app to place an order.

Comment: @Doug, The Zinc API need ASIN to place an order. But each ASIN represent one kind of items. These items may have different prices. They may be from different sellers. Through your API, which item it will place order? the one with low price or high price OR randomly?

Comment: @Doug - That's a pertinent question - Care to detail out/ clarify?